# Is there a way to forward a POST as a GET?

Tags: java, servlets, http-post, forwarding

I know that a forward preserves everything, including the method.  But is there a way around forwarding a POST as a GET?

I.e. is there a way to make the forward below become a GET so that the page to which we forward can access my session attribute?

```
 @Override
  protected void doPost(final HttpServletRequest req,
          final HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
      ...
      req.setAttribute("session", session);
      req.getRequestDispatcher("/myPage.jsp").forward(req, resp);
  }
```

Comment: Do you mean invoking `doGet(req, res)` at the end of `doPost()`?

Comment: Have you tried this?  Request attributes should be preserved through a forward.

Comment: @whirlwin. No, I want to hit myPage.jsp as a GET as the end of my doPost method.  My doGet method performs other unrelated operations and I do not want to invoke it.

Comment: are you sure you don't want to *redirect* instead of *forwarding* the request?

Comment: I'm pretty sure he wants to forward and not redirect as redirect would require two requests. He is probably doing this for URL rewriting.

Comment: I added some clarifications to my motivation.  I haven't tried yet using HttpServletRequestWrapper.

Comment: Well, I hate to say this but now my jsp picks up the session attribute even with the original code that I had.  I am confused why I had a problem earlier.  I will delete the description of my motivations for my question since they do not end up being correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [**HttpServletRequestWrapper**](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequestWrapper.html).

You wrap the request so that getMethod() returns `GET` then pass the wrapped request to your request dispatcher.

Answer (score 0):

The page can access the session and request attributes without any problem, because it is a single request when you forward.

I can't see your problem.